# Avidemux Tinypy Script Only Loading and Not Processing

Tags: python

I saved my settings and imported them into the batch skeleton, however, the only thing Avidemux does is LOAD the files, and that's it. It doesn't convert or process anything. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
gui=Gui()
adm=Avidemux()
ext="mp4"
inputFolder="c:\\tmp\\"
#
def convert(filein):
    if(0 == adm.loadVideo(filein)):
        gui.displayError("oops","cannot load "+filein)
        raise
        adm.videoCodec("Copy")
        adm.audioClearTracks()
        adm.setSourceTrackLanguage(0,"und")
        if adm.audioTotalTracksCount() <= 0:
            raise("Cannot add audio track 0, total tracks: " + str(adm.audioTotalTracksCount()))
        adm.audioAddTrack(0)
        adm.audioCodec(0, "Lame")
        adm.audioSetDrc(0, 1)
        adm.audioSetShift(0, 0, 0)
        adm.audioSetNormalize2(0, 2, 100, -30)
        adm.setContainer("MP4", "muxerType=0", "optimize=1", "forceAspectRatio=False", "aspectRatio=1", "displayWidth=1280", "rotation=0", "clockfreq=0")
        adm.save(filein+".converted.mp4")

    print("Done")

#
# Main
#

#
list=get_folder_content(inputFolder,ext)
if(list is None):
    raise
for i in list:
        convert(i)
print("Done")
```

Comment: Which line is the first line you expected to be executed but it isn't?

Comment: adm.videoCodec("Copy")

Comment: Why did you write `raise` in the line above?

Comment: that's what it showed in the batch skeleton for batch processing. should I take out raise and try running?

Comment: took "raise" out and ran it. same result as before.